# Need help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query that is trying to combine the following tables:

```
TABLE: orders_products
products_id
orders_id
products_quantity
products_price

TABLE: products
products_id
products_model
```

I want a query that returns the total number of sales, the total sales value for each product_id, and the product_model for each product in the orders_products table.  This is the best I've come up with so far and it just adds everything into the same bucket:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( op.products_quantity ) AS num_sold
  ,SUM( op.final_price * op.products_quantity ) 
  ,p.products_model
FROM orders_products AS op
JOIN products AS p
WHERE p.products_id = op.products_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `group by p.products_id` after your `where` and you will be good

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.products_id, p.products_model,
  SUM( op.products_quantity ) AS num_sold
  ,SUM( op.final_price * op.products_quantity ) AS sales
FROM orders_products AS op
JOIN products AS p
WHERE p.products_id = op.products_id
GROUP BY p.products_id, p.products_model
```

Comment: +1 You only need `GROUP BY p.products_id` in MySQL, the `p.products_model` is functionally dependend on `products_id`.

Comment: True, but most other databases do require it and assuming this makes the code that much more mysql dependent.  I prefer to try to write my SQL as database independent as possible, so I think it's a better practice to include all columns in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY.  Check this link:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp